# base de datos limit con parametros dependiente de consulta count

Tags: base-de-datos

mi pregunta es la siguiente tengo una consulta por ejemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM PERSONA LIMIT 0,5;
```

Hasta ahí todo bien, pero quiero que en vez del 5 me reciba una `consult count(*)`, por ejemplo:

```
 SELECT * FROM PERSONA LIMIT 0,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLA1);
```

El detalle es que cuando hago la consulta me genera error de sintaxis.

¡Agradezco la ayuda!

Answer (score 1):

Según el [manual de referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html):

> The `LIMIT` clause can be used to constrain the number of rows
>   returned by the SELECT statement. **`LIMIT` takes one or two numeric
>   arguments**, which must both be nonnegative integer constants, with
>   these exceptions:
>
> - Within prepared statements, LIMIT parameters can be specified using ? placeholder markers.
> - Within stored programs, LIMIT parameters can be specified using integer-valued routine parameters or local variables.

Rápidamente traducido: sólo admite valores numéricos directamente, salvo dos excepciones: en consultas preparadas, que puedes usar un marcador dinámico. O usar un procedimiento almacenado, donde admitiría, una variable local.

Apliquemos ambas soluciones:

#### Consulta preparada

```
SET @limitTwo=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLA1);
PREPARE STMT FROM 'SELECT * FROM PERSONA LIMIT O,?';
EXECUTE STMT USING @limitTwo;
```

---

#### Procedimiento almacenado

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE customLimit()
    BEGIN
    DECLARE limitTwo INT DEFAULT 1;
    SET limitTwo = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLA1) ;
    SELECT * FROM PERSONA LIMIT 0,limitTwo;
   END;
```

Lo llamamos para mostrar los datos:

```
CALL customLimit();
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias amigo cedano solo lo debo adaptar a un procedimiento mas grande que tengo por aca

Comment: De nada @CristianVillalba. Considera poner la etiqueta `mysql` a tu pregunta y darla por resuelta para que pueda ayudar a futuros usuarios. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

prueba esto.

```
DECLARE @Total int; 
SELECT @Total = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLA1);
SELECT * FROM PERSONA LIMIT 0,@Total;
```

Comment: creo que no funciona en mysq,l esa sintaxis es de sql server ?

Comment: Añade la etiqueta mySQL para que se vea

Comment: SELECT * from persona limit 0,@total
> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@total' at line 1
> Time: 0s                                                                                               este es el error

Comment: SET @total=(SELECT count(*) from sexo);

SELECT @total;
SELECT * from persona limit 0,@total;                                                    si establece en @total el total de filas que hay en la tabla sexo pero al momento de utilizarlo en la consulta de abajo sale ese error