# Usar una variable para el LIMIT en un SELECT de MYSQL con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Necesito hacer un `SELECT` en PHP donde se seleccionen de forma aleatoria X registros. Entonces estoy usando el método `ORDER BY RAND()`, pero necesito que el `LIMIT` sea uno u otro dependiendo de una variable, es decir, algo como esto:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT = '$limite'";
```

Según veo eso no funciona, y no creo que pueda hacerlo con las "Prepared Statements". Si es posible, me gustaría que aplicaran su respuesta al ejemplo anterior, me quedaría mucho más claro.

Gracias.

Comment: Lo vas a tener que hacer como un procedimiento almacenado el limit no acepta variables en la consulta fijate que podrias declarar una poniendo SET @datos := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabla); mostrar ese dato haciendo un SELECT @datos; pero al momento de poner esa variable en el limite da error SELECT * FROM otraTabla ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT @datos;

Comment: la variable `$limite` tiene que ingresar asi a la consulta `'".$limite."'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El Manual de Referencia dice que se puede usar una variable con `LIMIT` usando consultas preparadas.

Precisamente [ayer respondí sobre esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/214106/29967), sólo que en aquel caso se trataba de código directamente en el manejador.

Si es por PHP lo puedes hacer perfectamente mediante consultas preparadas:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ?";
if ($stmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql)){
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $limit);
    $stmt->execute();
    /*Verificar manejar resultados*/
    //...
}else{
    echo "Error en la consulta: ".$mysqli->error();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que concatenar tu variable al String:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ".$limite;
```

*También quitar la igualdad, ya que al LIMIT se le especifica directamente el valor.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es el `=` que esta en la declaración

deberias usar algo como:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT $limite";
```